# Campo data contando 7 dias após a data atual em c#

Tags: c#

Tenho uma campo na minha aplicação chamo `txt_dataemissão` no caso e a data atual, e tenho outro campo `txt_deadline` que preciso que me mostre nesse capo a data contada com 7 dias após a data de emissão, e desconsiderar os finais de semana, e possível fazer direto no código no c#, se sim como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta comparar se o dia é sábado ou domingo até que sete dias sejam somados

```
 DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txt_dataemissão.Text);   
 int dias = 0;
 while (dias < 7)
 {
    d1 = d1.AddDays(1);
    if (diaUtil(d1)) dias++;
 }
 txt_deadline.Text = d1.ToString();
```

o método diaUtil() ira dizer se o dia é sábado ou domingo

```
    private bool diaUtil(DateTime x)
    {
        if (x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: E se a data de emissão for sábado ou domingo?

Comment: Sua função `diaUltil` poderia ser simplificado em: `return x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday`

Comment: @PauloHDSousa são 7 dias para frente e não contando do mesmo '7 dias após a data de emissão'

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta era isso que precisava vlw.

Comment: Entendi, mas assim finais de semana estão fora de questão nesta ocasião, mas mesmo assim muti obrigado pela atenção de todos. Vlw

Comment: @Marconi para fazer mais sentido ao metodo, o melhor seria `return !(x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)` concordo com você em ser um melhor opção, mas assim achei q seria mais fácil ao AP compreender :)

Comment: @LeoLonghi então eu trocaria a ordem com que retorna os boleanos, faz mais sentido. `if (x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            return true;...` Mas de toda forma ficou bom :)